# Creating multiple dropdown buttons that will trigger a code when eddited in google sheets and apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, button

I have been making a google sheets document with buttons to make it more easy to use. This sheet will need to be used on my mobile phone. This is why I am using the drop down button with a onEdit(e) function in apps script. The point of the button is as follows:

I can click it on my phone and then I will get to choose a set of pre defined numbers. In this case : invoer,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6. When a selection is made, the chosen number will be added to the value in a specific cell. The code looks like this:

```
function onEdit(e) { *calls the function HVBBplus() when the cell J2 is edited
if (!e) {
}
if (e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'J2') {
return;
}
HVBBplus()

}

function HVBBplus(){
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var invoer = spreadsheet.getRange('J2').getValue();
var output = spreadsheet.getRange('K2').getValue();
spreadsheet.getRange('K2').setValue(invoer+output);
spreadsheet.getRange('J2').setValue("Invoer");
}
```

This works perfectly, but the problem is that I cannot figure out how to create multiple buttons with different codes. When I copy and paste the function onEdit, it will only run the second onEdit function and it will ignore the first one. Can someone please help me with this problem and maybe explain how this piece of code works exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it could be something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'J2') HVBBplus();
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'J3') HVBBplus2();
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'J4') HVBBplus3();
}

function HVBBplus(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var invoer = spreadsheet.getRange('J2').getValue();
  var output = spreadsheet.getRange('K2').getValue();
  spreadsheet.getRange('K2').setValue(invoer+output);
  spreadsheet.getRange('J2').setValue("Invoer");
}

function HVBBplus2(){
  // do something
}

function HVBBplus3(){
  // do something
}
```

The code can be improved if you describe what the 'buttons' you have and what exactly they supposed to do.

Just in case the same `onEdit()` function can be written with `switch/case` statement:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  switch (e.range.getA1Notation()) {
    case ('J2'): HVBBplus();  break;
    case ('J3'): HVBBplus2(); break;
    case ('J4'): HVBBplus3(); break;
  }
}
```

**Update**

The obvious optimization could be to add arguments into the function `HVBBplus()`:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  switch (e.range.getA1Notation()) {
    case ('J2'): HVBBplus('J2','K2');  break;
    case ('J3'): HVBBplus('J3','K3');  break;
    case ('J4'): HVBBplus('J4','K4');  break;
  }
}

function HVBBplus(cell1, cell2){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var invoer = spreadsheet.getRange(cell1).getValue();
  var output = spreadsheet.getRange(cell2).getValue();
  spreadsheet.getRange(cell2).setValue(invoer+output);
  spreadsheet.getRange(cell1).setValue("Invoer");
}
```

As a guess. I don't know your goal.

Comment: Thank you! This works :). What is the best place to find out how to use these codes myself? I found the code that I'm using on a google forum, but apparently " if (!e) {
} " isn't even needed.

Comment: It's a hardest question actually. I've learned this all on my own. Probably not the best way. Just googled it here and elsewhere. Try and see... etc. `if(!e)` looks weird in this particular case. But something alike can make sense to make the code work faster: no need to check many conditions if it is a wrong (empty?) object from the start.